# Jquery Menu slide in on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem with my menu.

This is the situation:

```js
 $(document).ready(function (){
  $('.btn').click(function (){
    $('.div1').fadeIn();
  });
})
```

```html
<button class="btn">Menu</button>
<div class="div1">some content</div>
```

This is what I have for now. So, I have that on button click, div fades in. But, I just can't do the next step. I want now that this 'div1' fades out on click anywhere else on the page, just not on that div and button.

Example: 
I click on 'btn', 'div1' shows up on the screen, then I move a mouse outside that 'div1' area and click anywhere else on the page, then 'div1' fades out (hide).

Can someone helps me with that please?

Tnx

Comment: Check this link:-http://html-tuts.com/jquery-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the div focusable with `tabindex="-1"`, then add an `.on('blur', function() {})` event to the div (and remove the focus outline with css):

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.div1').fadeIn();
  $('.div1').focus();
});

$('.div1').on('blur', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
  display: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Menu</button>
<div class="div1" tabindex="-1">some content</div>
```

Comment: I tried all, but this one worked perfect. Thank you Makaze... ;) you saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

Check click event target.

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).hasClass('.btn') && !$(event.target).hasClass('.div1')) {
        $('.div1').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: So, what happens when user clicks on something in the content of `div1`?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('body').click(function(evt){    
       if(evt.target.id == "main_btn")
          return;
       //For descendants of main_btn being clicked, remove this check if you do not want to put constraint on descendants.

  $('.div1').fadeOut();
       if($(evt.target).closest('#main_btn').length)
          return;             

      //Do processing of click event here for every element except with id main_btn
});
```

Snippet:

```js
$('.btn').click(function (){
      $('.div1').fadeIn();
  });

$('body').click(function(evt){    
       if(evt.target.id == "main_btn")
          return;
       //For descendants of menu_content being clicked, remove this check if you do not want to put constraint on descendants.
  
  $('.div1').fadeOut();
       if($(evt.target).closest('#main_btn').length)
          return;             

      //Do processing of click event here for every element except with id menu_content
  
  

});
```

```css
.div1 {
  display: none;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="main_btn" class="btn">Menu</button>
<div class="div1">some content</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Upon fading the `div1`, fade in a transparent div that fills the entire screen. Then handle a click to this fullscreen that will close everything.

html:

```
<button class="btn">Menu</button>
<div class="div1">
    <div class="screen"></div>
    <div class="content">some content</div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.btn').click(function (){
        $('.div1').fadeIn()
    })

    $('.screen').click(function () {
        $('.div1').fadeOut()            
    })
})
```

css:

```
.screen {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).click(function() {
//Hide the div1
});

$('.div1').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```